# npm run serve not working for metronic theme version 8.1.5

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel project , using vue 3 with it , when i am running npm run serve is gives the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.ts' in 'C:\laragon\www\marco_v2'
```

while running npm run watch it compiles it , and it is working fine , what can be the reason for the error. any help will be appreciated